# Sublime Text 2. Не компилируется c++ код под Ubuntu

Tags: sublime-text, c++, ubuntu

Здравствуйте. Я пытаюсь скомпилировать программу, написанную в Sublime Text 2.Но когда я нажимаю Build или Run, не происходит абсолютно ничего. А в окне Build Result пусто.
Вот мой конфиг:

```
{
"cmd": ["g++", "-Wall", "-Wextra", "-pedantic", "-std=c++11",   "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
    }
]
}
```

Вот то, что я пытаюсь скомпилировать:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
std::cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста это исправить.

Comment: g++ установлен?

Comment: Может:

    std::endl;

Comment: Всё равно, нажимаю и build и run, ничего не происходит

Comment: @devnikor, кардинально это правится переходом на make и запуском  вручную, из командной строки.

Возможно Ваш редактор (Sublime Text 2, насколько я понимаю, это редактор) позволяет запускать команды ОС и получать результат в окошке или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: @avp, да, это редактор, мне бы не хотелось запускать вручную, т.к. планируется установить плагин для отладки и, тем самым, сделать из этого редактора более-менее полноценную ide

Comment: А [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/tour/) чем не устраивает?

Comment: @devnikor, возможно. 

Хотя, я думаю, Вы просто не представляете всех возможностей (даже уже "из коробки") этой *среды программирования* (это я об Emacs).

Comment: То, что есть конфиг, есть не факт, что выбрана правильная "BuildSystem" (Tools->Build System ->...)
Но может все происходит, а просто консоль не открыта. нажмите ctrl+` (` - это слева от единички).

Comment: @KoVadim, сделал как вы сказали, но теперь ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 337, in run_
  File "./exec.py", line 130, in run
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 62-68: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Вспоминайте, какие файлы саблима правили, и забыли сохранить в utf-8. А дальше сохраняйте в правильной кодировке.

Это питоновский интерпретатор ругается. он увидел символы, которых в юникоде не может быть.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Используйте полноценные IDE (Eclipse, Code::Blocks, NetBeans, Anjuta, KDevelop и т.д.).
Sublime Text 2 - это текстовый редактор(не является компилятором), чтобы его правильно настроить [читайте документацию.](http://sublimetext.ru/documentation) Также проверьте установлен ли g++, по умолчанию в Ubuntu он не ставится, чтобы это проверить в командной строке введите `apt-get install g++`.

Answer (score 0):

Проверь, чтобы не было кириллицы в пути